# How to create a Power ON-Power OFF tone

Tags: power

I'm working on a simple alarm project and would like to build a circuit which gives a short tone when the alarm is armed and also a again once disarmed.can I do this with a 555? I am a begginer so am trying to keep things simple, And also what would the name of this type of circuit be called?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A circuit that generates a given frequency (tone) is called an oscillator or astable multivibrator. The slightly more difficult part here is that you want a short tone, not one of indefinite length. That short tone could be done with  mono-flop, monostable multivibrator or single shot (all the same). Simplest solution today would be to implement it in a microcontroller, but there is no fun in that when learning electronics.

Comment: whenever you power/off your alarm you need a sound indication.right?

Comment: My first comment is inaccurate, you would use the single shot to turn on the oscillator for a brief moment. Do youhave a circuit diagram of the alarm you're working on?

Comment: @jippie Your first comment works too: Use a piezo buzzer :-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh A piezo buzzer is no fun when learning electronics... But yeah it is the simplest solution to make a sound. At user30432: These make a continuous sound: http://www.adafruit.com/products/160 you just have to switch them on and off.

Comment: @yogece I would like a sound indication when powering on and powering off

Comment: @jippie I don't have a circuit diagram,am just sort of winging it and hopefully pick things up as I go.will start googling the single shot and an oscillator now I know what Im meant to be looking for,thanks

Comment: What electrical signal or stimulus can you use in your alarm circuit to trigger the short-duration tone. This might be the hardest part.

Comment: @Andyaka the alarm would be switched on via a remote relay. My thinking was if I could use the power from that some how, so as when I activate the alarm it would start a timing circuit which would in turn sound the alarm briefly (to make a bleep sort of sound)then when the power is switched off another signal would be sent to bleep again.would the use of AND gates get me any where nearer to a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You need to trigger the sound when the alarm is armed and again when it is disarmed. Detecting the rising and falling edges of the arm/disarm signal will give you just that. This can be done with a simple XOR gate and a resistor/capacitor delay.

[image]

With both inputs LOW the XOR output is LOW and the astable (or you could use a buzzer instead) is OFF.

When the arming signal goes HIGH input A goes high immediately but the uncharged capacitor (C1) holds input B LOW. This gives a HIGH on the output (C) and turns the sound on. The capacitor charges through the resistance (R1) and after a short time (determined by the time constant R1 x C1) the input B goes HIGH and the output C goes LOW - turning the sound OFF.

No further sound is made until the systen is disarmed when the input A goes LOW.

When A goes LOW, input B is still HIGH because the capacitor is charged. The out put C will go HIGH and turn on the sound. The capacitor then discharges through R1 bring B LOW after a short time (determined by the time constant R1C1) bringing the output (C) LOW and turning OFF the sound.

If you wish to make one sound longer than the other you can add a resistor and two diodes to the delay circuit given them different time constants for rising and falling edges.

The IC is a 4070 type (quad XOR)
[image]

Comment: @yogece From a lot of years designing and building electronic circuits. ;)

Comment: @JImDearden thankyou for your reply. I will have to see about gathering some components to breadboard your circuit but reading the discription the concept seems right.thanks again

Comment: @JImDearden even i thought the same after seeing this http://www.edn.com/design/components-and-packaging/4423513/Connect-passive-components-to-logic-gates-

Comment: @JImDearden. Sorry quick question.just looking at the 4071 ic data sheet so can order the component but it says that it's an OR gate.am i looking at the wrong data or does the x come from the other components within the circuit if so is it due to the diodes Or is my thinking incorrect

Comment: @user30432 My apologies, its my failing eyesight and small text - got the wrong chip number, its the 4070 (quad XOR) not the 4071 (quad OR). Have corrected the schematics accordingly.

Comment: @JImDearden thank you have bread boarded the above circuit and it works great thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

A second (and more modern) approach would be to use a small micro controller (one of the 8 pin types but any simple micro controller would do). You only need ONE input and ONE output to achieve the same effect as the other solution but this circuit has the added advantage of being able to produce a different frequency for ON and OFF. This would involve programming the chip but it would make a suitable first project in using a micro controller.

[image]

Metacode (basic steps in the program)

Initialize (set up internal oscillator, initialise which pin is input, which output)

LOOP   (start of program label)

Wait for alarm INPUT to go LOW to HIGH     (alarm set)

TONEALARMSET

for 1 second
output 1kHz tone

Wait for alarm input to go HIGH to LOW

TONEALARMUNSET

for 2 seconds
output 500Hz tone

jump back to LOOP